# Filter all objects of array A whose id occur in array B

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two arrays - A & B.

A:

```
name: string;
id: string;

{name: 'Hans', id: 0; name: 'Caleb', id: 1; name: 'Emily', id: 2}
```

B:

```
name: string;
collections: [numbers]

{name: 'Pure', collections: [0,2]}
```

**How can I filter all objects of array A whose IDs occur inside of B's `collection`?**

I tried the following but could only filter for one static id:

```
const result = this.a.filter(value => value.id === this.b.collections[???];
```

Comment: Do you need to match the name when filtering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `includes()`

Try like this:

```
a = [{ name: 'Hans', id: 0 }, { name: 'Caleb', id: 1 }, { name: 'Emily', id: 2 }]

const result = this.a.filter(value => this.b.collections.includes(value.id));
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wdkvij)**

Answer (score 1):

If you need to match the name.

```
const result = this.a.filter(value => {
  const matchWithName = this.b.find(e => e.name === value.name);
  if (matchWithName) {
     return matchWithName.collections.includes(value.id);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```